# Getting the amount of days a person is employed - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass, studio3t

I am new to mongodb and I have a task to calculate the amount of days a person is/was employed and get the 5 employees, who were employed for longest time. I have written some code, but the amount of days is always null. Here is my code:

```js
db.getCollection('employees').aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$jobs" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "lodging",
      localField: "jobs.host_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "lodging"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$lodging" },
  { $match: { "lodging.isActive": true } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "jobs.DaysEmployed": {
        $cond: {
          if: { $ne: [ "$jobs.endDate", "" ] },
          then: {
            $divide: [
              {
                $subtract: [
                  { $toDate: "$jobs.endDate" },
                  { $toDate: "$jobs.startDate" }
                ]
              },
              8.64e+7
            ]
          },
          else: {
            $divide: [
              { $subtract: [ "$$NOW", { $toDate: "$jobs.startDate" } ] },
              8.64e+7
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      surname: { $first: "$surname" },
      dateBirth: { $first: "$dateBirth" },
      sumDaysEmployed: { $sum: "$jobs.DaysEmployed" },
      arrayOfDocuments: { $push: "$jobs" },
      host_info: { $push: "$host_info" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "sumDaysEmployed": -1 } },
  { $limit: 5 }
])
```

I am working with a set of collections `lodging` and `employees`.

Here is a sample data of `employees`:

```json
  {
    "_id": "61c06971bb210e90e6cd9003",
    "jobs": [
      {
        "salary": "$5977.43",
        "start": "2018-12-20T00:00:00",
        "end": "",
        "host_id": "5bf31f8c718c0eea19d8b1e7"
      },
      {
        "salary": "$5542.61",
        "start": "2015-12-20T00:00:00",
        "end": "2018-12-20T00:00:00",
        "host_id": "5bf31f8cfc2601a6424484a0"
      },
      {
        "salary": "$6584.55",
        "start": "2012-12-20T00:00:00",
        "end": "2015-12-20T00:00:00",
        "host_id": "5bf31f8ce3d117c148b91f50"
      },
      {
        "salary": "$3493.60",
        "start": "2009-12-20T00:00:00",
        "end": "2012-12-20T00:00:00",
        "host_id": "5bf31f8cd50e2bfc8aa296ef"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Barrett",
    "surname": "Mosley",
    "dateBirth": "1951-02-12"
  }
```

Here is a sample of `lodging`:

```json
  {
    "_id": "5bf31f8c856a12c73c888cee",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "f99844b5-7ecd-4c90-860f-b79a742fcac1",
    "isActive": true,
    "registered": "2012-06-14T02:14:30 -02:00",
    "host": {
      "name": "Grimes",
      "surname": "Terrell",
      "gender": "male",
      "age": 55,
      "picture": "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/GrimesTerrell.png",
      "languages": [
        "spanish",
        "slovenian",
        "english"
      ],
      "contact": {
        "company": "QUANTALIA",
        "email": "grimesterrell@quantalia.com",
        "phone": "+1 (987) 474-3543"
      },
      "reviews": [
        {
          "reviewer": "Mae Ryan",
          "date": "2015-06-01T02:41:46 -02:00",
          "helpful": 8,
          "kind": 1,
          "responsive": 5
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Nixon Johnson",
          "date": "2016-02-08T10:35:12 -01:00",
          "helpful": 1,
          "kind": 1,
          "responsive": 9
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Dorothy Copeland",
          "date": "2016-07-17T12:44:31 -02:00",
          "helpful": 3,
          "kind": 3,
          "responsive": 4
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Kathleen Roth",
          "date": "2014-12-26T04:38:36 -01:00",
          "helpful": 10,
          "kind": 3,
          "responsive": 5
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Hallie Hart",
          "date": "2016-02-14T10:21:50 -01:00",
          "helpful": 9,
          "kind": 4,
          "responsive": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    "lodging": {
      "price": "$86",
      "address": {
        "street": "645 Louisa Street",
        "city": "Fairhaven",
        "state": "Nebraska",
        "coordinates": [
          5.439653,
          30.761532
        ]
      },
      "amenities": {
        "parking": true,
        "petsAllowed": true,
        "airConditioning": true,
        "elevator": true
      },
      "reviews": [
        {
          "reviewer": "Susanne Walton",
          "date": "2018-03-20T04:50:18 -01:00",
          "cleanliness": 8,
          "location": 1,
          "food": 10
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Henrietta Manning",
          "date": "2017-12-14T07:05:46 -01:00",
          "cleanliness": 10,
          "location": 5,
          "food": 1
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Newman West",
          "date": "2018-05-07T05:23:55 -02:00",
          "cleanliness": 9,
          "location": 10,
          "food": 6
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Brennan Rowland",
          "date": "2016-09-20T04:49:15 -02:00",
          "cleanliness": 10,
          "location": 1,
          "food": 8
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Beulah Lambert",
          "date": "2016-04-20T11:51:43 -02:00",
          "cleanliness": 4,
          "location": 8,
          "food": 9
        },
        {
          "reviewer": "Joseph Mcdowell",
          "date": "2015-02-10T12:14:20 -01:00",
          "cleanliness": 7,
          "location": 9,
          "food": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Each employee is/was employed in a specific lodging. They are connected by `id`. `"host_id"` in `employees` is the `lodging` `"_id"` - the lodging where that person is/was employed.

Comment: Your words don't say it, but your query seems to show that you don't want to count days employed if the `lodging` is not currently active?  Is that your intention?

Answer (score 0):

Your query attempt seems to show something else, but if you really just want to:

> calculate the amount of days a person is/was employed and get the 5 employees, who were employed for longest time

... then here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "daysEmployed": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$jobs",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$sum": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$dateDiff": {
                  "startDate": { "$toDate": "$$this.start" },
                  "unit": "day",
                  "endDate": {
                    "$cond": [
                      { "$eq": [ "$$this.end", "" ] },
                      "$$NOW",
                      { "$toDate": "$$this.end" }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$sort": { "daysEmployed": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 5 }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NSUqj4-1YAm).